# How to display new ViewController on orientation change?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to recreate an effect similar to the iOS Music app in that I want a completely new view to appear in my app when the phone flips from vertical to horizontal (the Music app shows album covers). And I can't quite seem to get it working. So far I've tried variations of the following:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    TMFHorizontalFavoritesViewController *horizontalVC = [[TMFHorizontalFavoritesViewController alloc] init];

    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation)) {
    [self presentViewController:horizontalVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

But at best all I seem to get is a black screen. I've tried googling and searching here on Stackoverflow for similar questions, but I can't seem to piece together the right answer. If anyone has any input it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Where are you creating TMFHorizontalFavoritesViewController's view? Storyboard? Xib?

Comment: Created it in storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's one piece of advise I could give new iOS programmers, it would be never ever instantiate a view controller with alloc init (there are times when it's legit, but newbies almost always get it wrong).

This is how you do it with a storyboard defined controller,

```
TMFHorizontalFavoritesViewController *horizontalVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I'll definitely keep that in mind going forward (only a few weeks into learning Objective-C and iOS). Is there any chance you should tell me why this broke what I was trying to do?

Comment: @ImpurestClub, Using alloc init creates a new view controller with a blank view since you haven't told the controller where to get its view from. You should use initWithNibName:bundle: if you make the view in a xib, and the method in my answer for a controller made in a storyboard. It's ok to use alloc init, if you create the view in code, which you do by overriding loadView.